# If you set the font-size, will you determine the height the element occupies?

Tags: css

Let's say you have a div containing a line of text which you have set the font-size to 16px. Will you be able to determine height of the div? I guess not. I mean the font-size does not seem to correlate to the height of a line of text. What is exactly a font-size? the pixel count of the width of a letter?

The reason I'm asking this is I need to be able to set the font-size of a line of text and also determine the height of the text. Any good ideas?

Comment: You can not depend on the font size solely if you want to set the div´s height since every browser implements the fonts differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the line-height too!

```
element {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

This will make the element have a height of 16 pixels. This allows you to center text vertically too. However, setting the line-height doesn't change the font-size.

Comment: Hi if you know the font size, is there any way to determine the minimum line-height(or default?) that can contain the line of text without it "overflowing"?

Comment: @Aperture that's very difficult. Fonts are rendered differently per browser per OS. Not to mention non-standart fonts! If you just don't touch the line-height, the browser's generated line-height should be the practical minimum though.

Comment: There is a problem then: Let's say I need to set the font-size to 16px and also need to know the div height. To determine the height of the div, I have to set it explicitly to 20px. To make sure the text is vertically centered, I also need to set the line-height to 20px. But a line-height of 20px may be too big for a font-size of 16px, so I need to set line-height to 18px. But in this case, it may cause "overflow". So you have to guess the minimum line-height, which is not convenient...